# C++/CLI value class constraint won't compile. Why?

Tags: generics, c++-cli

a few weeks ago a co-worker of mine spent about two hours finding out why this piece of C++/CLI code won't compile with Visual Studio 2008 (I just tested it with Visual Studio 2010... same story).

```
public ref class Test
{
    generic<class T> where T : value class
        void MyMethod(Nullable<T> nullable)
    {

    }
};
```

The compiler says: Error

> 1 error C3214: 'T' : invalid type
>   argument for generic parameter 'T' of
>   generic 'System::Nullable', does not
>   meet constraint 'System::ValueType
>   ^'    C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Projektdokumentation\GridLayoutPanel\Generics\Generics.cpp   11  1   Generics

Adding `ValueType` will make the code compile.

```
public ref class Test
{
    generic<class T> where T : value class, ValueType
        void MyMethod(Nullable<T> nullable)
    {

    }
};
```

My question is now. Why? What is the difference between `value class` and `ValueType`?

P.S: See the Nullable definition for C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Comment: I agree, the value class constraint should have been enough.  I think your workaround is correct.  You could try connect.microsoft.com to see what they'll say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I analyzed the IL code of the three following methods:

```
generic<class T> where T : value class, System::ValueType
    static void MyMethod(T arg)
{

}

generic<typename T> where T: value class
    static void MyMethod2(T arg)
{

}

generic<typename T> where T: ValueType 
    static void MyMethod3(T arg)
{
}
```

The corresponding IL-code, which I dissassembled with .NET-Reflector:

```
.method public hidebysig 
 static void MyMethod<valuetype ([mscorlib]System.ValueType).ctor T>
(!!T arg) cil managed
{
}


.method public hidebysig 
static void MyMethod2<valuetype .ctor T>(!!T arg) cil managed
{
}


.method public hidebysig
static void MyMethod3<([mscorlib]System.ValueType) T>(!!T arg) cil managed
{
}
```

This is the IL-declaration of `Nullable<T>`:

```
.class public sequential ansi serializable sealed beforefieldinit 
Nullable<valuetype (System.ValueType) .ctor T>
    extends System.ValueType
```

As you can clearly see, only the first method's constraint matches 100% with `Nullable<T>`'s. (Btw: `value class` seems to imply the presence of a standard constructor). However, why the compiler produces different IL-code for (semantically) the same constraints, remains still a mystery. I will ask Microsoft's C++/CLI Gurus for further information.

Answer (score 0):

[`ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) is special in that it is the "base class" of value types, but not a value type itself. This is probably the issue here.

A nice list of the different entities which are used by the CLR can be found in [this excellent blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/joelpob/archive/2004/07/19/187709.aspx).

See also [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0cc56569-e6e5-4222-8039-f0739b3d780c) and [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e749d964-ef65-40cd-bcee-bfe25d5747f8) for some more information specific to the `ValueType`.

Comment: Thanks for your researches, Lucero.